# Using Dedekind Cut to construct multiplicative inverse in $\Bbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, real-numbers

I was trying to construct a multiplicative inverse in terms of Dedekind cuts: Fix some $\alpha\in\Bbb R^*$ (that means the positive real numbers), we define the identity element $1^*$ to be $$1^*:=\{q\in\Bbb Q\mid q<1\}$$ The multiplicative inverse candidate that I use is defined,$$\beta:=\{p\in \Bbb Q\mid \exists\, r\in 1^*:\frac{r}{p}\notin \alpha\}$$

I was able to show how $\beta$ is a cut and how $\alpha\beta \subseteq 1^*$. But I got stuck when trying to understand why $1^*\subseteq \alpha\beta$. Here is my attempt.

> Pick some $c\in 1^* (c<1)$, then there exists $a\in\alpha$ and $b\in \Bbb Q\setminus \alpha$ such that $$
> \frac{b}{a} < \frac{1}{c}\tag{1}$$which implies that $$\frac{a}{b}>c \tag{2}$$
> Therefore there exists some $r\in 1^*$ such that $$\frac{ar}{b}=c=a\left(\frac{r}{b}\right)\in \alpha \beta$$ Therefore we conclude that $1^*\subseteq \alpha\beta$.

I want to know if it's rigorous for me to derive my first two inequalities (1) and (2) and if it's okay to go from $\frac{a}{b}>c$ directly to the fact that $\exists\,r\in1^*:\frac{ar}{b}=c$. If not, could you please let me know the necessary steps to arrive at the desired conclusion $1^*\subseteq \alpha\beta$? Thank you so much!